# Access resultset value of cfprocresult name in cfif

Tags: sql, coldfusion, cfc

I am new to ColdFusion and want to rewrite my project from ASP.NET to learn ColdFusion step by step.

My SQL Server stored procedure for authentication (ASP.NET) looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_auth
@suser  VARCHAR(20),
@spswd  VARCHAR(20)
AS
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users.SUsers WHERE suname=@suser AND supasswd=@spswd AND off_bit=0
GO
```

Application.cfc  snippet.

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="sp_auth" datasource="cftraderelay">
<cfprocparam value="#cflogin.name#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" maxlength="20" type="in">
<cfprocparam value="#cflogin.password#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" maxlength="20" type="in">
<cfprocresult name="auth_pass" maxrows="1">
</cfstoredproc>


<cfif auth_pass GTE 1>
<cfloginuser name="#cflogin.name#" password = "#cflogin.password#" roles="#roles#"> 
<cfelse>
<cfoutput>
<h2>Your login information is not valid.<br> Please Try again</h2> 
</cfoutput>
<cfinclude template="login.cfm">
<cfabort>
</cfif>
```

What is right form of 'cfif auth_pass GTE 1' logic? How to access the value of 'auth_pass'.
Cos I get "Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values" error by far.

Am I strictly supposed to use out type of cfprocparam in this case, not cfprocresult (modify SQL query for the OUTPUT variable)?

Can I access cfprocresult value right in the cfif statement?

Comment: You're right to use cfprocresult in your call to cfstoredproc. What comes back though is a query object. change your `SQL to SELECT COUNT(*) AS auth_count ...` then you can use `auth_pass.auth_count` in your code

Comment: Not related to your question, but you have an odd combination.  Your procresult specifies maxrows = 1 and your check looks for >= 1.  Even if there are two records in the database, ColdFusion will only accept 1 because of the maxrows attribute.

Comment: 2 Dan Bracuk — The check looks for >= 1 as of result value "1" or greater, not as recordCount rows counter. It supposed to be always a single row statement.

Comment: And yeah, it could be and old ASP.NET misused feature as well. Better check for EQ 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auth_pass` contains a recordset, not a number, so you cannot compare it to 1. You perhaps want `auth_pass.recordCount`?

The best tool for examining the contents of a variable is [`<cfdump>`](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldusionlatest/cfdump). That and familiairising yourself with the docs for the code you're using, eg: [`<cfprocresult>`](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldusionlatest/cfprocresult), [`<cfstoredproc>`](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldusionlatest/cfstoredproc), [`<cfquery>`](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldusionlatest/cfquery) (the latter for details on query objects) if you run into problems and can't guess the solution.

Comment: No, no. Not auth_pass.recordCount. I need something like auth_pass.value or GetValue(auth_pass). The auth_pass value should be 1, if 0 that means login incorrect. auth_pass.recordCount is always 1.

Comment: Thanks! <cfdump var="#auth_pass#"> works right out of Application.cfc Now check it like <cfif auth_pass.COMPUTED_COLUMN_1[1] GTE 1> Works and looks very odd! Is it all right?

Comment: That's fine. If it's a single-row resultset, you can omit the row index. I tend to specify it anyway though.

Comment: As an aside, unnamed resultset columns default to `COMPUTED_COLUMN_X`. You may want to add an alias for the SQL count, ie `SELECT count(*) AS NumOfUsers ... `. Then you can reference it by the alias name instead ie `<cfif auth_pass.numOfUsers[1] gt 1>`. There is no technical difference, but descriptive names make code easier to follow.